Connecting a USB A "host" to a USB C DFP, what happens?
My question is a twist on this post from a few years ago about what happens when connecting two USB-C "hosts":
Instead of the devices both having USB-C ports, what if one had a USB-A port? For example, you connect a USB-A-->USB-C cable between two wall chargers: one charger having a USB-A port and the other a USB-C port.
USB-A doesn't have CC lines, so the explanation in the linked post becomes less straightforward. USB-A also always has the VBUS line live when plugged in, so I am wondering how this would be mitigated on the USB-C end of the cable.
My guess is that USB-A-->USB-C cables internally pull the the CC line high to indicate a DFP on the USB A side. Am I onto something?

Nothing would happen.
If you have a cable with Type-A and Type-C plugs, then then inside the Type-C plug must be a resistor from CC to VBUS as per the USB standard to signal that it is the host side intended to be plugged into a device.
Also as per the USB standard, the supply with Type-C receptacle must not enable VBUS out to receptacle, unless it detects from the CC pins that a device that requires a supply is plugged in. And since it does not detect such a connection, it will not enable the VBUS, and as per the USB robustness requirements, this scenario must be handled properly - i.e. nothing will happen, the two power supplies will not be shorted together.

So every USB-A to USB-C cable has these pullups (provided it was made to spec)? I am wondering if this is something I can count on, or if my design should be able to handle a case where a USB-A to USB-C cable does not have these resistors.

You design a device with a USB port to follow the standards for the type of port you're using. It's up to the user to use the right cable.

@oneil You can assume  a compliant and non-broken A-to-C cables have a correct resistor and work with all devices. You can also assume that some of the cheapest cables are not made properly, may have incorrect resistor and they don't even carry the USB logo and do not work with any device and is not a valid USB cable. But that is not the problem of your device, which then cannot determine if something is plugged in or not.
